# Why is a bulk insert to a memory-optimized non-durable table the same speed as a durable table?

Tags: sql-server, memory-optimized-tables

When running a large bulk insert to a durable and a non-durable memory optimized table, I'm getting the same speeds for both. Shouldn't the speed of of a bulk insert to a non-durable memory-optimized table be faster than a durable memory-optimized table? If so, what am I doing wrong here?

My test is as below, it takes ~30 seconds consistently. This is on SQL Server 2016 SP1. The bulk insert is 10 million rows from a csv file that I generated.

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE Users_ND (
  Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED HASH WITH (BUCKET_COUNT=10000000),  
  Username VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL  
) WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED=ON, DURABILITY = SCHEMA_ONLY);  

CREATE TABLE Users_D (
  Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED HASH WITH (BUCKET_COUNT=10000000),  
  Username VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL  
) WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED=ON, DURABILITY = SCHEMA_AND_DATA);  

SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
SET NOCOUNT ON;  

BULK INSERT Users_ND 
FROM 'users-huge.csv' 
WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', BATCHSIZE = 1000000);

BULK INSERT Users_D 
FROM 'users-huge.csv' 
WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', BATCHSIZE = 1000000);
```

users-huge.csv

```
Id, Username
,user1
,user2
...
,user10000000
```

Comment: What is your Delayed Durability setting? If it doesn't start writing to disk before the data is all loaded, the load would definitely take the same time. Also, consider disk write caching that may exist on your system.

Comment: Also consider that CPU rather than I/O may be the limiting performance factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I had this issue due to the fact that the source file for the bulk insert was saved on a slow HDD, so there was a bottleneck in reading the file.